# Getting error while comparing resultset object's data in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I tried a code in JSP in which I have 2 databases n I have to get a value from database 1 n compare with the value from the another database. All the data got works well. Even it printing on page. But not comparing with it.

This is the code which I tried.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%! 
String userName;
int marks;
int i=3;
String obj1,obj2;
int whileCount=0;
%>

<%
    userName=request.getParameter("u_n");
    try
    {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:login_dsn");
    Connection con2=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:model_ans");

    Statement st1=con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    String query="select * from login where id="+userName;
    ResultSet res1=st1.executeQuery(query);

    Statement st2=con2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet res2=st2.executeQuery("select * from model_ans");

    res1.first();
    res2.first();

    i=3;
    marks=0;

    do
    {
    obj1=res1.getString(i);
    obj2=res2.getString(2);
    whileCount++;

    out.println(obj1+"  "+obj2+"       " );     

    if(obj1.equals(obj2)==false)
        marks++;

    i=i+1;  
    }while(res2.next());

    out.println("total while count:"+whileCount);
    whileCount=0;

    out.println("Total marks:"+marks);

    con1.close();
    con2.close();

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
     out.println(e.toString());
    }
%>
```

The data base query is like :

1.First DB:

```
create table login(id number,password text,q1 text,q2 text,[upto 30],q3 text);
```

2.Second DB:

```
create table model_ans(id number,Ans text);
```

Comment: Where are you facing the problem ? Sidenote : You can use `!obj1.equals(obj2)` instead of `==false` .

Comment: Actually I had changed it to obj1.equals(obj2) but don't know whats happening, the code isn't going in that block. So I changed it to false. and the same problem here goes, all time that loop goes in to that block. Even the above above out.println(t1+" "+t2) showing me its the equal one. 
Okkey, let me summarize my problem: for the code lines
if(obj1.equals(obj2)) marks++;
 ^ This block is not getting executed. Even though they are same.